# Import with 'require' cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, resharper

In VS2019 16.2.1, I created a new project using the Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application with TypeScript Template.

[image: Template choice]

I can build and run the application.

However, in app.ts, if I hover over the line

```
import debug = require('debug');
```

I see a tooltip

```
Import with 'require' cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher
```

[image: Warning message]

Here is tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Why do I see this message and what should I do about it?

[Update]

I tried changing the first line to

import debug from 'debug';

then I get build errors

```
app.ts(1,8): error TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/kirst/source/repos/ExpressApp1/ExpressApp1/node_modules/@types/debug/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag
```

[Update] 
The warning dissappears when I suspend Resharper Ultimate.

If I switch to ES5 and try

```
import from 'debug'  ( with or without a semicolon )
```

I see an error

```
can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag
```

[image: esMOdule Interop flag]

If I use

```
import * as debug from 'debug'
```

It works

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
import debug = require('debug');
```

you should use

```
import * as debug from 'debug' // Import everything from that module
// OR
import debug from 'debug' // Import only the class 'debug' from that module

// Depends on the module
```

This is the new Syntax in ES6

<sub>[(Read more)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)</sub>

If you want to use the old style of importing modules you can set `"target"` to `"ES5"` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: After changing to the proposed answer, the compiler might still show that you need to install @node/types. you dont need that actually. I applied the answer at the question to resolve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857459/this-module-is-declared-with-using-export-and-can-only-be-used-with-a-defau

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to change those imports to this style:

```
import debug from 'debug';
```

Or in `tsconfig.json` set `"target"` to `"ES5"` or `"ES3"`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the attempt to change the style.

Comment: chainging tsconfig.json works.  ( or suspending resharper )